# Rails Rspec Capybara Selenium JS create not showing after pressing submit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

I am building a web shop, the functionality is already there, namely: in ONE screen there is a list of products and a list of ordered items. When in a product pressing order, this product then shows up immediately in this list.

As you can guess, when wanting to do this with a test, using selenium I see Firefox starting up, I think I even see the button being pressed, but then obviously nothing happens. No item in my order list.

Using Rails 5 with an updated capybara and selenium webdriver.

```ruby
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5', '>= 3.5.1'
gem 'capybara', '~> 2.10', '>= 2.10.1'
gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.7"
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 3.0'
gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.5', '>= 1.5.3'  
gem "email_spec", "~> 1.6.0"
```

**creating_order_spec.rb**

```ruby
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature 'User can fill his shopping cart', js: true do
  let!(:category) { FactoryGirl.create(:category, name: 'Honey') }
  let!(:cheap_product) { FactoryGirl.create(:product, name: 'Honey lolly', 
                                                      price: '0,80',
                                                      category: category) }
  let!(:expensive_product) { FactoryGirl.create(:product, name: 'Honeyjar 400ml', 
                                                      price: '3,95',
                                                      category: category) }

  before do
    visit categories_path
  end

  scenario 'with different products' do
    page.find('.product', :text => 'Honey lolly').click_button('ADD TO CART')
    page.find('.product', :text => 'Honeyjar 400ml').click_button('ADD TO CART')

    within('#order') do
      expect(page).to have_content 'Honey lolly'
      expect(page).to have_content 'Honeyjar 400ml'
      expect(page).to have_content 0.80 + 3.95
    end
  end
end
```

**Database_cleaning.rb**

```ruby
RSpec.configure do |config|  
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end    

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Then I run it and get:

```text
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content 'Honey lolly'
       expected to find text "Honey lolly" in "Total € 0,00"
```

Which means that nothing has happened to my order, or the total would have been more than € 0,00.

**EDIT**

This is the JS that only somehow doesn't work in tests.

```ruby
$('#order').html("<%= j render 'orders/order' %>")
```

**EDIT 2**

**test.log**

```js
Started POST "/bookings" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-14 10:11:00 +0100
Processing by BookingsController#create as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "booking"=>{"product_id"=>"1", "product_quantity"=>"5"}}
  [1m[36mProduct Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35m (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[36mBooking Exists (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "bookings" WHERE "bookings"."order_id" IS NULL AND "bookings"."product_id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["product_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[31mROLLBACK[0m
  Rendering bookings/create.js.erb
  Rendered orders/_order.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered bookings/create.js.erb (2.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 14ms (Views: 4.8ms | ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)
```

Seems that there is no SQL statement triggered for the order. While normally it should be to fill in the total.

**bookings_controller.rb**

```ruby
def create
  @booking = @order.bookings.find_by(product_id: params[:booking][:product_id])
  if @booking
    @booking.product_quantity = params[:booking][:product_quantity]
    @booking.save
  else
    @booking = @order.bookings.new(booking_params)
    @product = @booking.product
    @booking.product_name = @product.name
    @booking.product_price = @product.price
  end
  @order.save
  respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to categories_path }
      format.js { render layout: false }
  end
end
```

`order.save` triggers an extra method called `.sum_all_bookings`. This is not showing up in the SQL. Herein lies somewhere the error of the order staying unchanged in the view (#order).

Comment: What is the full error you get?

Comment: Added the error at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely cause is an error in one of your JS assets that's preventing the behavior you're expecting from being attached.  Things can work fine in dev mode when the assets aren't concatenated (so an error in one file doesn't prevent the other files from being processed), but then fail in the test and production environments when an error in one file can prevent the JS concatenated after it from being parsed/processed.

Additionally you find 2 (I assume they are different since you're expecting 2 products to be added) elements with id = Product ('#product').  That is invalid html since ids are required to be unique, so could lead to weird issues.

Comment: I have added the JS. Still haven't got this test working.

Comment: Somebody has time to check this with the added EDIT. What @ThomasWalpole is saying is most likely true: Something with the JS in the test environment is not working as in development. Still stuck to find out what this is though.

Comment: @Code-MonKy  What does your test.log show as far as the requests the app received?  Also you didn't comment on the fact that you have two elements with the same id?  Could you add your actual html for that part of the page.

Comment: In my app I changed all id's that could be multiple to classes. I added the controller and the test.log file part that is relevant.

Comment: @Code-MonKy Due to dirty checking, `save` will only save (and trigger your sum_all_bookings method) the object if the object has changed.  In your case it hasn't.  This is probably (assuming bookings is a has_many association on Order) due to you using `.new` to create your booking rather than `.build` which would create the new booking associated with the order - `@booking = @order.bookings.build(booking_params)`

Comment: There is indeed something strange going on with the has_many relationship of bookings on an order. When I add bookings with `<<` to the order the `sum_all_bookings` works fine, but when creating from `order.bookins` having the right `order_id` in the booking doesn't work I found out in the console. Bookings is now a join table object as well to retrieve product info, making things really complex.